# Insert records into two tables using single view in Django rest framework

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework, model

I have three models as follows.

```
class Quiz(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   desc = models.CharField(max_length=500)    
   number_of_questions = models.IntegerField(default=1)
   time = models.IntegerField(help_text="Duration of the quiz in seconds", default="1")

   def __str__(self):
       return self.name

   def get_questions(self):
       return self.question_set.all()

class Question(models.Model):
    ques = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
       return self.ques

class Answer(models.Model):
   content = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   correct = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

   def __str__(self):
       return f"question: {self.question.ques }, answer: {self.content}, correct: {self.correct}"
```

I have to create api for create question. for this I have to use model Question and Answer same time  e.g.
[image]

its admin page but I want to create same api which accept above parameters and store it into database.
how to write view.py for this api ?

Comment: I don't know if you have much experience with DRF, but I recommend to start with the [tutorial](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/), work through the example, and then you will have a good starting point to writing your view.

Comment: @Matthew Hegarty  yes, I am new in DRF